# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect?

Tags: xampp

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\theglorykart\includes\config.php:2
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\theglorykart\includes\header.php(11):
>   include_once() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\theglorykart\index.php(2):
>   include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\theglorykart\includes\config.php on line 2

Comment: Welcome. Please modify the question a little to include what the application or plugin is and how this problem occurred. I.E did it always work, new project etc.. Also include useful info if you can such as your application and Php versions you are using.

Comment: i am useing the xmapp , php verson  7.1.7 , this is the static website which i want to setup on xampp server but i am facing this problem